# What is the "Unused" field in a Debian package control file? Is it official?

Tags: debian, deb

```
Package: a package name
Version: FROM GIT
Section: base
Priority: optional
Architecture: armhf
Depends: "some deps"
Unused: "some packages names"
Provides: lp304-base-installer
Maintainer: someone name
Description: desc
```

Comment: [5.3. Binary package control files – DEBIAN/control](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#binary-package-control-files-debian-control)

Comment: @Greenonline do u think i did not look there already?! search the page for unused and you will find nothing.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): `Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!`

Comment: @Greenonline Sorry i should have said this field is not documented, still i need to understand it. what unused filed actually dose there?

Comment: Dose it remove the packages from the dependency chain installed with depends filed? or dose it remove it from the system, or its just a false positive not used unused!

Answer (score 2):

There is no defined “Unused” field, whether [in binary `control` files](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#binary-package-control-files-debian-control) or [in source `control` files](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#debian-source-control-files-dsc), so this entry has no effect.

If I had to guess, I imagine the packages listed in this entry are of some interest to the package, but are currently unused — perhaps they are needed to enable some feature in the packaging which isn’t quite ready yet. I would use a comment instead.

Comment: Great now i understand thanks